# md-card is not taking full width

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am trying to create a form which will take full width using md-card.

```
<md-card>
  <md-card-content>
    <h2>Settings</h2>
    <section class="form-section">
      <md-slide-toggle>Toggle Theme</md-slide-toggle>
    </section>
  </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

associated Css

```
.form-section{
  display: flex;
  align-content:center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

it is appearing like

[image]

I wants setting forms to be appear in the middle of page or md-card should take full width.

I am using Angular 2 and Angular Material 2. Please help

Comment: I read doc about md-card, there does not seem to be any explaination that it will take full width.
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdCard

Comment: need to apply class on md-card, not on inner elements in order to make it 100%

Comment: @WasifKhan You're looking at the AngularJS Material docs, **NOT** the Material2 Docs. The docs are here: https://material.angular.io/components/card/api

Comment: BTW, it would be best to use `@angular/flex-layout` for flex layout. [More info](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout)

Comment: It is full width for me when i copy paste the html you are using. What version of material are you using?

Comment: @WasifKhan The one needing help is Ashish, I was guiding on how to resolve the issue.

Comment: @Ashish, can u make plnkr example of your code so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

Define a css class in your component's css:

```
.full-card {
     width: 100%; /* or try width: 100vw; */
}
```

Apply this class to your card:

```
<md-card class="full-card">
    <md-card-content>
        <h2>Settings</h2>
        <section class="form-section">
            <md-slide-toggle>Toggle Theme</md-slide-toggle>
        </section>
    </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is **align-items: center** that is stopping the card from filling the flex container. If you remove that and set the flex direction to column it will stretch to full width.

```
        <div class="form-section">
            <md-card>
                <md-card-content>
                    <h2>Settings</h2>
                    <section class="form-section">
                        <md-slide-toggle>Toggle Theme</md-slide-toggle>
                    </section>
                </md-card-content>
            </md-card>
        </div>
```

**css**

```
    .form-section {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-content:center;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: @Ashish strange there must be some other styling applied. Can you share your full html and css?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was with the `display: flex;`, and I fixed it by removing it.